# Stored procedure with table name as parameter 

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

I have a stored procedure, and I would like to assign the number of rows of that table to a variable and later use that variable.

I am calling the procedure like:

```
EXEC TEST.dbo.myProc nameOfTable
```

The procedure is something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc @table_name varchar(1024) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @Nval INT
    /*  SOME INSTRUCTIONS */

    SELECT   @Nval  = COUNT(*) FROM @table_name 
END
```

When executing I am getting an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure nLQ, Line 57
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

How would I assign the variable `@Nval`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tablenametest]
@table_name varchar(50),
@PMId int,
@ValueEq int

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)
SET @cmd = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + 
' WHERE Column1 = ''' + @PMId +  '''' +
' AND Column2= ''' + @ValueEq + ''''

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd 
END
```

Answer (score 15):

You can't parameterise a table name like that, `FROM @table_name`. Only way is to execute dynamic TSQL.

Before you do that, read: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: And if I do it dinamically, How can I assign the count to a variable `Set @Statement = ' SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @table_name;
 EXEC (@Statement);`  where do I recover the value?